# Mapreduce job gzip compression failure

Tags: hadoop, zlib

I have setup a new cluster (using HDP on Windows ) and I am encountering a new problem which I haven't seen before.

When I run a simple word count problem from hadoop-examples jar the MapreduceV2 job fails with below error

```
5/05/16 18:58:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1431802381254_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher#15
```

Now,when I go to Application Master tracker  and dig into logs I find that reducer is expecting a gzip file but the mapper output wasn’t

```
2015-05-16 18:45:20,864 WARN [fetcher#1] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher: Failed to shuffle output of attempt_1431791182314_0011_m_000000_0 from <url>:13562
java.io.IOException: not a gzip file
```

When I specifically drill into Map phase log,I see this

```
2015-05-16 18:45:09,532 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory: Failed to load/initialize native-zlib library
2015-05-16 18:45:09,532 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.gz]
2015-05-16 18:45:09,532 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile: Could not obtain compressor from CodecPool
```

I have the following configurations in my core-site.xml

```
<property>     
  <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec</value>
   <description>A list of the compression codec classes that can be used for compression/decompression.</description>   
</property>
```

and in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>  

<property>     
   <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec</value>   
</property> 

<property>     
   <name>mapred.output.compression.type</name>        
   <value>BLOCK</value>
</property> 

<property>     
  <name>mapred.output.compress</name>
  <value>true</value>   
</property>   

<property>     
   <name>mapred.output.compression.codec</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec</value>   
</property>
```

> Now I realise this is pointing to error in native zlib dll loading,so I ran the job overriding options to run without compression and it **does** work.

I have downloaded the zlib.dll from [zlib site](http://www.zlib.net/) and placed it in Hadoop/bin , C:\system32 and C:\SystemWOW64 folders and restarted the cluster services but still I have same error. Not sure why.I would appreciate any ideas to debug this further and resolve it

Answer (score 0):

**Hadoop 2.7.2**

I ran into the same issue, when I built and ran hadoop 2.7.2 on windows 7. To resolve the issue you need to do the following:

1) On the Build Machine: set ZLIB_HOME to the zlib headers folder **zlib_unzip_folder\zlib128-dll\include** and build the distribution.

2) On the Run Machine make zlib1.dll **zlib_unzip_folder\zlib128-dll\zlib1.dll** available on the path.

I used zlib 1.2.8 and the download link can be found here: http://zlib.net/zlib128-dll.zip

**Hadoop 2.4.1**

This issue can also be reproduced on an older version of HADOOP by setting native lib as false and forcing map output to be compressed. For More detail you can see here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11334